# Why does Solution Explorer context menu 'Add Class' default to Xamarin Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm running VS2017 Community v15.5.1, and when I right-click on the Solution Explorer and select `Add->Class...`, I get an `Add Item` dialogue that defaults to Xamarin Forms and a Xamarin page[see image]. Before the upgrade of VS, when did the same, a simpler dialogue opened just asking for a class file name.

This is damned annoying and unproductive, as each time I want to add a class, I have to deselect `Xamarin.Forms` on the dialogue and select `ASP.NET Core` before I get prompted for a class name.

Is there any way I can fix this?

The dialogue I get now:
[image]

Comment: I see the same thing. Yes it is very annoying. The only workaround I have found is Add > New from Template but that is added by Resharper

Comment: Workaround could be to use a keyboard shortcut or create one if not exist. Beside that there should be away to contact Microsoft and suggest an improvement.

Comment: @EvZ I have long ago reported this, and it looked like they fixed it until the latest upgrade. I have just reported it again and maybe they will pull their fingers out and get it fixed properly.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne All good for a workaround: I do have ReSharper, thanks.